# Are Java constructors only called when they are parameterized?

Tags: java, parameters, constructor, default-constructor

Apparently Java thinks my constructor code is not important, so it completely ignores it and then yells at me with a NullPointerException when I try to access an ArrayList that I thought was initialized. Only when I add an arbitrary parameter to my constructor does Java think it's worth looking at.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DataManager {
    ArrayList<Variable> vars;

    public DataManager() {
        vars = new ArrayList<Variable>();
    }

    public void createVar(String type, String name, String strValue, int numValue) {
        vars.add(new Variable(type, name, strValue, numValue));
    }
}
```

And the code that calls this:

```
DataManager data = new DataManager();
data.createVar(...);
```

Variable class:

```
class Variable {
    String type;
    String name;
    String strValue;
    int numValue;

    public Variable(String type, String name, String strValue, int numValue) {
            this.type = type; this.name = name;
            this.strValue = strValue;
            this.numValue = numValue;
    }
}
```

Running this results in

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
>       at Parser.start(Parser.java:25)
>       at SudoCode.go(SudoCode.java:10)
>       at SudoCode.main(SudoCode.java:6)

So... what's the deal? Why are constructors ignored when they aren't parameterized? It's just not very intuitive. Was this some sort of design choice that I can't see the obvious implications of? If so, enlighten me. And should I just add an arbitrary parameter so the constructor is executed, or should I create and explicitly call a method designed solely to initialize my ArrayList?

Thanks!

Comment: No, this does not happen. You have made a mistake.

Comment: Thanks, Tom. It would be great, then, if someone could help me spot my mistake. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: your obove code looks fine, my guess is you are accessing something null in Variable() constructor, can you post Variable's const as well .. :)

Comment: I've run this code. Both classes' constructors get called. Voting to close.

Comment: Just leave this question, Tom, if you have nothing constructive to add

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your assumption is false. You cannot instantiate an object without having its constructor execute.

If you define a class without a constructor, Java will create an implicit ("default") constructor without parameters.

Comment: Sorry, It's just that my constructor code was not called: that is, it did not execute. Or, more specifically, the ArrayList was not initialized and my System.out.print(); test did not show up.

Comment: Just post the stack trace as well.

Comment: Just did, and it's different - no longer the NullPointerException... not sure what I changed

Comment: You may have to stop blaming Java for NPEs. :)

Comment: Yeah yeah yeah... I always blame the language first because I know it's always my fault. But it's a kind of sarcasm for me :p

Comment: No worries. Others do that as well.

Answer (score 2):

the best way of initializing attributes of a class is at the point of declaration if possible. The initialisation will be executed before the code in the constructor indifferent of which constructor you use. So if you have multiple constructors you save lines of code. In your case use:

```
public class DataManager {
    ArrayList<Variable> vars = new ArrayList<Variable>();

    public DataManager() {
    }
}
```

Comment: Really? Didn't know that was possible - I thought you could only instantiate classes from within methods.

Comment: check this out: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html

Answer (score 0):

If you do not define a constructor, JAVA uses the default constructor:

```
public MyClass() {
}
```